# Bootstrap radio button: get selected value on submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the next Bootstrap radio buttons:

```html
<div class="btn-group" id="filterDay" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="1"> Monday
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="2"> Tuesday
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="3"> Wednesday
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="4"> Thursday
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="5"> Friday
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="6"> Saturday
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default blue active">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="0"> Sunday
  </label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the value of the active button when I submit the form, without creating an `onclick` event, simply getting the active button from the `$('#filterDay')` button group. It should be easy but I didn't find a way to get the value. I tried several examples but all didn't work.

**Update:**

This is the HTML "printed" code:

```
<label class="btn btn-default blue">
    <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="6"> Saturday
</label>    
<label class="btn btn-default blue active">
    <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="0"> Sunday
</label>
```

The `active` value in the `class` attribute is what is changing when I click the button.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In the form submit handler, use the [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector.

```js
var filterDay = $('#filterDay input:radio:checked').val();
```

Comment: Then try `var filterDay = $('#filterDay label.active input').val()`

Comment: It's better to delete the above comment and include that in the answer, that would be clearer.

Answer (score 15):

You should set a common `name` attribute to identify the form:

```html
<div class="btn-group" id="filterDay" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle" value="1"> Monday
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle" value="2"> Tuesday
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle" value="3"> Wednesday
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle" value="4"> Thursday
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle" value="5"> Friday
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default blue">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle" value="6"> Saturday
    </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default blue active">
      <input type="radio" class="toggle" name="toggle" value="0"> Sunday
   </label>
</div>
```

And to get the value like this:

```js
$('input[name=toggle]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
$( "input:checked" ).val();
```

Check jQuery's documentation for more information about [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector and [`.val`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Some logic problem is in the code:

```html
<label class="btn btn-default blue active">
    <input type="radio" class="toggle" value="0"> Sunday
</label>
```

The label has the `active` class so Bootstrap will display it as active but the contained input radio is not checked, so in pure HTML, it is not checked.

Correct code:

```html
<label class="btn btn-default blue active">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" class="toggle" value="0"> Sunday
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector.

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery's [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) attribute, just like this:

```js
$('#radioButtonName').prop('checked');
```