# Bootstrap radio button group not marking radios as checked

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-group

I'm having a few issues with Bootstrap 3 radio button groups.

When I select the radio button, it is not marking the radio button as checked, it is only adding 'active' to the radio label.

So when I try and pull the checked radio button via PHP and Codeigniter specifically there are no values.

Should the radio buttons not work as a normal radio button should?

Here's the radio button code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Custom Branding">Custom Branding</label><br />
    <div class="btn-group user_toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm active">
            <input type="radio" name="default_branding" value="0" autocomplete="off" > No
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            <input type="radio" name="default_branding" value="1" autocomplete="off"> Yes
        </label>
    </div>  
</div>
```

So when I click a radio button, neither of the radio buttons are marked as checked.

And the radio buttons are only in the POST array if a change has been made, but I need all the values there.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673985/bootstrap-radio-button-get-selected-value-on-submit-form

Comment: Why would i want to use a JS solution to recreate very simple HTML behavior?

Comment: Does this plunker with just bootstrap achieve what you want?: https://embed.plnkr.co/SYqwJ1MQUQJOCKoxN1Pl/  (look at the console to see the logged value of whether each button is checked)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your problem, but your code is not logic. You have active class on the label so bootstrap display "No" as active, but you don't have "checked" attribute in the corresponding radio input so in pure html it is not checked.

your code with the checked attribute corresponding to the active class...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Custom Branding">Custom Branding</label><br />
    <div class="btn-group user_toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm active">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="default_branding" value="0" autocomplete="off" > No
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            <input type="radio" name="default_branding" value="1" autocomplete="off"> Yes
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but when i check/select a radio button, it DOESNT mark that radio button as checked?!